# Why is it that our memories (from childhood up and till now) are to be remembered at the time of death?

Tags: death, commentary, isha-upanishad, shankara

While reading the Isha Upanishad (with the commentary of Shankara) I came across a saying of his (i.e. Shankara) that at the time of death one should remember their memories. You can find this in his commentary on the Isha Upanishad verse 17. It reads:

> Time has come for me to remember what I should. Remember all that I have till now

This is said to be done at the time of death, as he says this in his commentary:

> Now, as I am dying

So why is it that one should remember all of his memories at the time of death?